# Python How to build a *real* ip address multi-client server

Tags: python, sockets, ip

let's say I have a multi-client server socket and a client socket in python.

Server: (You don't have to read all of the server's code, just know it's a multi-client server.

```
import socket, select

CONNECTION_LIST = []    # list of socket clients
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 # Advisable to keep it as an exponent of 2
PORT = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# this has no effect, why ?
RealServerIP = ? # I want to have a real server ip which would let me connect to the server from any computer around the globe...
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((RealServerIP, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)

# Add server socket to the list of readable connections
CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket)

print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

while 1:
    # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
    read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])

    for sock in read_sockets:

        #New connection
        if sock == server_socket:
            # Handle the case in which there is a new connection recieved through server_socket
            sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
            CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd)
            print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

        #Some incoming message from a client
        else:
            # Data recieved from client, process it
            try:
                #In Windows, sometimes when a TCP program closes abruptly,
                # a "Connection reset by peer" exception will be thrown
                data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                # echo back the client message
                if data:
                    sock.send(data)

            # client disconnected, so remove from socket list
            except:
                broadcast_data(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                print "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr
                sock.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                continue

server_socket.close()
```

(example from http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/).

And 3 clients which are the most simple clients you can imagine to yourself:

```
import socket # imports module named 'socket'
RealServerIP = ? # I need your help here.... read the continuation
my_socket = socket.socket() # creates new socket named 'my_socket'
my_socket.connect((RealServerIP, 5000)) # connects to the server
my_socket.send(str) # sends string to the server
data = my_socket.recv(1024) 
print data # prints data
my_socket.close()
```

I wanted to check whether my server can comunicate with those 3 clients at the same time. So I want to make my server as a public server like a web-server of Facebook, etc.
So any computer around the world could connect to it.

So, I tried to figure out how would I store my python server socket online with a specific IP and PORT which has nothing to do with my localhost, I want it to be real! Like any chat/web server you know..

Comment: You need to bind to your ip address instead of the loop-back interface. Or forward at your router/firewall to whichever address/port the server is bound to.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the IP which the user connect with it to the internet, I don't think there is a way to get it by `socket` module, But i got a way to do the same thing using `requests` module if this may help.

```
import requests

def get_ip():
    url = 'https://www.cmyip.com'
    user_ip = requests.get(url).content.decode("utf-8").split("My IP Address is ")[1].split(" <a class=")[0]
    return user_ip
```

I hope this help.

Note: This was tested on python 3.4.3 and it is working fine. I don't know about 2.X versions.